# Запрос к Яндекс.Трекер API

Tags: php, php-curl

Пытаюсь получить данные от яндекс.трекера с помощью curl, например, как описано здесь https://yandex.ru/dev/connect/tracker/api/get-user-info.html.
Запрос составляю так :

```
public function actionTestRequest(){
        $access_token = "";
        $client_id = "";
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/myself');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Host: 'https://api.tracker.yandex.net'",
            "Authorization: OAuth $access_token",
            "X-Org-ID: $client_id"
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return json_encode($response);
    }
```

В ответе ничего нет.
Как сделать правильно?)

Answer (score 0):

В CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER "Host" не нужен.

```
    $access_token = "";
    $client_id = "";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/myself');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Authorization: OAuth $access_token",
        "X-Org-ID: $client_id"
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return json_encode($response);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]